# Laravel 5 how to manipulate my variable in an for each in my controller and then pass it to my view

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, explode

I have a database table named 'services'. With the function below I get all the records from that table. This function is located in my ServicesController.php.

```
public function index() {
  $roadmap = Roadmap::all();


  return view('services', compact('roadmap'));
}
```

Now in my view I also do the following:

```
<?php
        foreach($roadmap as $roadmap_item) {
              $new = array();
              $splitted = explode("|", $roadmap_item->steps);

              foreach($splitted as $split) {
                $new = explode(":", $split);
              }
            }
?>
```

Lets say I get the string 'step1:hello|step2:bye' back from '$roadmap-item->steps'. I split them in substrings with explode etc. This is working by the way.

But is there a way I can manipulate the string in the Controller so my view will be nice and clean without many php code and still remain the variable $roadmap with all the database records.

Kind regards,

Dylan

Comment: maybe you find it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers

Comment: in controller may be using array concatenating you can do it with only one variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do very similar things in your controller. Do foreach in your controller first then make a changes in every item in your collection and pass the new collection.

For example:

```
$roadmaps = Roadmap::all();

foreach($roadmaps as $roadmap){

  $roadmap->something = " the changes you want to do as string " . $roadmap->something;
  $roadmap->save();

}

return view('services', compact('roadmaps'));
```

or

```
  $roadmaps = Roadmap::all();
       $new = new Collection();

        foreach($roadmaps as $roadmap){

          $new[] = array('roadmap' => $roadmap, 'something' => $roadmap->string . " etcetc ")
          $new->save();

        }

        return view('services', compact('new'));
```